# How do I use a function argument as a name of a variable that I assign to input() in the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

How do I use a function argument as a name of a variable that I assign to input() in that function?

I want to make the second argument the name for the variable at line 6.

How do I do that?

Here's my code:

```
import os

def number_tuple(tuple, outputvar):
  """neatly format a tuple!"""
  for i, item in enumerate(tuple,1):
      print(i, ' = ' + item, sep="")
      outputvar = input()
      os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') 


mytuple = ("Something", "Something else", "Something else")
number_tuple(mytuple, myoutput)
print(myoutput)
```

EDIT: So I basically want to let the user choose a thing from the tuple (by entering 1, 2, etc) and then I want to assign a variable to the user input. Because I'm gonna use this function a lot in my program, I want to be able to name each individual "user input variable" in my function arguments. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: I would let other more experience user confirm but I think that in general it is not a good idea to "dynamically" assign variable. Or maybe you could detail exactly why you would need to change the name of a variable ? Wouldn't it be enough to achieve your goal with: `fixed_name_output = number_tuple(mytuple)`

Comment: can you explain your problem clearly, as it is not well explained, going through your code, you assign input value to a variable which you can already pass through as functional argument?

Comment: I think he is looking a way to name the output of his function with a user input.

Comment: So I basically want to let the user choose a thing from the tuple (by entering 1, 2, etc) and then I want to assign a variable to the user input. Because I'm gonna use this function a lot in my program, I want to be able to name each individual "user input variable" in my function arguments. Hopefully that makes sense.